# Проверка поля на существование в БД (PYMYSQL)

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, pymysql

Использую Python 3 и Pymysql.

Есть файл txt и БД с десятками тысяч значений. Как можно сделать проверку на существование записи в БД?

Т.е. беру значение с .txt проверяю есть ли в БД такое значение, если есть - пропустить, если нет - добавить. Начало кода у меня есть, но с проверкой засада, не понимаю как ее написать.

```
f = open('C:/ENG.txt', "r", encoding='UTF8')

for line in f:
    time.sleep(1)
    line = line.replace('\n', '')

    try:
        a.execute("SELECT * FROM Top WHERE name LIKE '" + line + "'")
```

Спасибо за любую помощь!

Comment: [INSERT <blah-blah> IGNORE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html) - если есть ограничение на уникальность какого-нибудь столбца, то при попытке вставить одинаковое значение ничего не произойдет.

Answer (score 1):

> если есть - пропустить, если нет - добавить

Простейший вариант - использовать INSERT IGNORE. Записи, которые нарушают требования уникальности, будут проигнорированы. Правда, необходимо наличие уникального индекса по требуемому полю или совокупности полей.

Более сложный вариант (тоже требующий наличия уникального индекса) - использование INSERT .. ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE, причём в секции UPDATE выполняется формальное присвоение какому-либо полю (например, ключевому) его текущего значения. Либо, если необходимо, можно выполнить полное либо частичное (только отдельные поля) обновление существующих данных.

Ещё вариант - это использовать REPLACE INTO. Такой запрос вставит отсутствующие записи и обновит существующие записи новыми значениями. Уникальный(ые) индекс(ы) также необходим(ы).

Если же уникальный индекс отсутствует, то остаётся использовать разве что INSERT ... SELECT ... WHERE NOT EXISTS (...).

**UPD:**

> Расскажите подробнее

Ну схематично это типа

```
INSERT INTO table (field1, field2) 
SELECT @value1, @value2 -- значения-литералы
FROM dual 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
                  SELECT 1 
                  FROM table 
                  WHERE field1 = @value1 -- проверка на существование
                 )
```

Если проверяемого значения нет, условие во WHERE истинно, SELECT вернёт 1 запись, которая будет вставлена.

Если проверяемое значение существует, условие во WHERE ложно, SELECT вернёт 0 записей, и вставка выполнена не будет.

Это - суть. В Вашем случае это потребует обрабатывать текстовый файл по одной записи, и для каждой генерировать и выполнять такой запрос. Если в файле больше нескольких штук записей, разумнее рассмотреть вариант загрузки всех их во временную таблицу (скажем, через LOAD DATA INFILE, или потоковым INSERT .. VALUES) и последующую вставку одним запросом типа

```
INSERT INTO table (fieldset)
SELECT (temptable.fieldset)
FROM temptable
LEFT JOIN table ON (table.fields = temptable.fields)
WHERE table.idfield IS NULL
```

Comment: Увы, у меня нет уникального поля. Расскажите подробнее пожалуйста об INSERT ... SELECT ... WHERE NOT EXISTS (...).